# Tableview rows in a section have issues when displayed

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have two sections in a table view. 1st section has a switch. Second section has 3 switches. Based on the state of switch in first section I either animate to hide section 2 or animate to show section 2.

Everything works fine except of below.

When the switch in section 1 is toggled to ON alternatively , I see that the rows in section 2 get screwed up a bit. Screenshot below.

[image: Section 2 when Switch in section 1 is ON]
Next time when I turn on switch to ON, it looks good. I see the issue happening when I toggle switch in section 1 to ON every second time.

[image: Second time when Switch in section 1 is toggled to ON]

Code snippet to insert and Delete section:

```
TableView.BeginUpdates();
                        TableView.InsertSections(new NSIndexSet((nuint)1), UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom);
                        TableView.EndUpdates();

TableView.BeginUpdates();
                    TableView.DeleteSections(new NSIndexSet((nuint)1), UITableViewRowAnimation.Top);
                TableView.EndUpdates();
```

Can you point why section 2 is screwed up when the section is inserted every second time.

Comment: Cells are reused.  It looks like you don't reset the layer corner rounding correctly when a cell is reused.  Sometimes the cell that was originally at the top is reused in the middle or the bottom.  Show your `cellForRow` function and the code where you set the corner radius

Comment: Thanks. That is the issue. I will reset the cell to get rid of old corner radius values when it is reused.